# How can I start my journey in Dart & Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello Stackoverflow community! I'm sorry for this question, I know that this was asked so many times but I need some guidance for my journey as a mobile developer. So... like I said earlier, I want to be a mobile developer, but I don't want to learn 2-3 programming languages for developing apps ( like Java and Swift or obj-c ) My dream is to master Dart & Flutter. The problem is that I have NO IDEA how to programm. I bought some courses but they explain things for people who actually know the programming basics or fundamentals. Do I need to start learning something else? Do I need to buy books? (If this question is in the wrong category, please move it but don't delete the question, thanks!!!)

Answer (score 4):

Flutter actually has a get started page on it's website located [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install).

That will initially walk you through installation and some early apps.

If you run into trouble with any of those applications you can post your specific issues here for help.

Comment: @NituAlexandruCostin Follow the tutorials, that's the usually best way to learn a language. I learned dart through those tutorials. Granted I did already have programming knowledge. If you find those tutorials to be too overwhelming than I would suggest learning python from https://www.w3schools.com/python/ or a video on youtube or any other source. However my advice is to just try it first, take it slow, don't skip steps and you will learn eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Flutter's official partner for their online bootcamp course. It's well done and is only $10!

https://www.appbrewery.co/p/flutter-development-bootcamp-with-dart

One note, however, the one language you learn will not be the only language you learn if you plan to stick with this for a while. Learning one language naturally folds into learning more. I started by learning Swift because I wanted to build my own app. Eventually my customers told me that they wanted an Android version, so I learned Flutter. While it may seem daunting that you always have more to learn, it's what makes being a mobile developer so fun and exciting!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I heard that you need to master Dart language and then learn Flutter framework

Comment: I wouldn't set out to learn them separately. Just start following tutorials and making some stuff that excites you!